# Can we enable encryption through CMK customer managed keys for Azure Data factory via ARM Tempalate?

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory

```
 "resources": [
      {
          "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
          "name": "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
          "identity": {
              "type": "SystemAssigned,UserAssigned",
              "userAssignedIdentities": {"/RESOURCE ID": {}}},
          "properties":
          {
              "repoConfiguration": "[if(equals(parameters('EnableGit'),bool('true')), variables('repository'), json('null'))]",
               "encryption": {
                   "vaultBaseUrl":"XXX",
                   "KeyName":"XXX",
                   "keyversion":"XXX"
               },
               "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled"
          } 
      }
  ]
```

The above lines are part of the ARM TEMPLATE I have used for Data factory encryption. Please let me know the working lines of JSON.

Comment: am getting the below error with this template    "code": "CustomerManagedKeyUserAssignedManagedIdentityNotFound",
    "message": "Create or update failed. User assigned identity user in CMK Encryption is not assigned to the factory.",

Comment: Did you follow my answer to create a new ADF? Please use my template and parameters carefully, it works fine on my side.

Comment: yes I did.I will try again

Comment: @JoyWang also can you please explain what does the other 2 resource sections of your template do #managedvirtualnetwork and #integration runtime . TIA

Comment: They are two default resources if you create the ADF in the portal, feel free to use the template, It is an empty ADF    the same as the one you create in the portal.

Comment: It is taking longer than usual time to execute this template

Comment: Simply remove the two resources, it will be faster. See my Update, it also works fine.

Comment: Could you achieve this now?

Answer (score 1):

Try the template that works for me, it creates a datafactoryv2 with `Customer managed key` enabled, replace the values in **`parameters.json`**, `/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/joymsi1` is the `resource id` of the [user-assigned managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-manage-ua-identity-portal), make sure you have created one and [add it to the keyvault access policy with correct key permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/enable-customer-managed-key#grant-data-factory-access-to-azure-key-vault).

**`Template.json`**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "defaultValue": "myv2datafactory",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "version": {
            "defaultValue": "V2",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "eastus",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "apiVersion": {
            "defaultValue": "2018-06-01",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "tagsByResource": {
            "type": "Object"
        },
        "vNetEnabled": {
            "defaultValue": false,
            "type": "Bool"
        },
        "publicNetworkAccess": {
            "defaultValue": true,
            "type": "Bool"
        },
        "gitConfigureLater": {
            "defaultValue": true,
            "type": "Bool"
        },
        "gitRepoType": {
            "defaultValue": "FactoryVSTSConfiguration",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitAccountName": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitProjectName": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitRepositoryName": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitCollaborationBranch": {
            "defaultValue": "master",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitRootFolder": {
            "defaultValue": "/",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
            "defaultValue": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "type": "Object"
        },
        "userAssignedIdentitiesStr": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "vaultBaseUrl": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "keyName": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "keyVersion": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "enableCMK": {
            "defaultValue": false,
            "type": "Bool"
        },
        "cmkIdentity": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": "[ if(contains(parameters('tagsByResource'), 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories'), parameters('tagsByResource')['Microsoft.DataFactory/factories'], json('{}')) ]",
            "identity": "[if(parameters('enableCMK'),json(parameters('userAssignedIdentitiesStr')), parameters('userAssignedIdentities'))]",
            "properties": {
                "repoConfiguration": "[if(bool(parameters('gitConfigureLater')), json('null'), json(concat('{\"type\": \"', parameters('gitRepoType'), '\",','\"accountName\": \"', parameters('gitAccountName'), '\",','\"repositoryName\": \"', parameters('gitRepositoryName'), '\",', if(equals(parameters('gitRepoType'), 'FactoryVSTSConfiguration'), concat('\"projectName\": \"', parameters('gitProjectName'), '\",'), ''),'\"collaborationBranch\": \"', parameters('gitCollaborationBranch'), '\",','\"rootFolder\": \"', parameters('gitRootFolder'), '\"}')))]",
                "publicNetworkAccess": "[if(bool(parameters('publicNetworkAccess')), 'Enabled', 'Disabled')]",
                "encryption": "[if(bool(parameters('enableCMK')), json(concat('{\"identity\":{\"userAssignedIdentity\":\"', parameters('cmkIdentity'), '\"},','\"VaultBaseUrl\": \"', parameters('vaultBaseUrl'), '\",','\"KeyName\": \"', parameters('keyName'), '\",','\"KeyVersion\": \"', parameters('keyVersion'), '\"}')), json('null'))]"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/managedVirtualNetworks",
                    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('name'), '/default')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('name'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {},
                    "condition": "[and(equals(parameters('version'), 'V2'), parameters('vNetEnabled'))]"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes",
                    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('name'), '/AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('name'))]",
                        "[concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('name'), '/managedVirtualNetworks/default')]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "Managed",
                        "managedVirtualNetwork": {
                            "referenceName": "default",
                            "type": "ManagedVirtualNetworkReference"
                        },
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "computeProperties": {
                                "location": "AutoResolve"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "condition": "[and(equals(parameters('version'), 'V2'), parameters('vNetEnabled'))]"
                }
            ],
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('version'), 'V2')]"
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories",
            "apiVersion": "2015-01-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[if(equals(parameters('version'), 'V1'), parameters('location'), 'eastus')]",
            "tags": "[ if(contains(parameters('tagsByResource'), 'Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories'), parameters('tagsByResource')['Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories'], json('{}')) ]",
            "properties": {},
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('version'), 'V1')]"
        }
    ]
}
```

**`parameters.json`**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "name": {
      "value": "joyfactory1"
    },
    "version": {
      "value": "V2"
    },
    "location": {
      "value": "centralus"
    },
    "apiVersion": {
      "value": "2018-06-01"
    },
    "tagsByResource": {
      "value": {}
    },
    "vNetEnabled": {
      "value": null
    },
    "publicNetworkAccess": {
      "value": true
    },
    "gitConfigureLater": {
      "value": true
    },
    "gitRepoType": {
      "value": "FactoryVSTSConfiguration"
    },
    "gitAccountName": {
      "value": null
    },
    "gitProjectName": {
      "value": null
    },
    "gitRepositoryName": {
      "value": null
    },
    "gitCollaborationBranch": {
      "value": "master"
    },
    "gitRootFolder": {
      "value": "/"
    },
    "userAssignedIdentities": {
      "value": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      }
    },
    "userAssignedIdentitiesStr": {
      "value": "{\"type\": \"SystemAssigned,UserAssigned\", \"userAssignedIdentities\": {\"/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/joymsi1\": {}}}"
    },
    "vaultBaseUrl": {
      "value": "https://joykeyvault123.vault.azure.net/"
    },
    "keyName": {
      "value": "joyfactorykey1"
    },
    "keyVersion": {
      "value": "d5dca2a5xxxxx3998c5"
    },
    "enableCMK": {
      "value": true
    },
    "cmkIdentity": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/joymsi1"
    }
  }
}
```

**Besides**, if you just want to enable the customer-managed keys in an existing datafactory, I think it is unnecessary, because a customer-managed key can only be configured on an empty data Factory, if there are some resources in it, you need to delete all of them first, so it is easier to create a new data factory directly with customer-managed keys enabled.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/enable-customer-managed-key#enable-customer-managed-keys

[image]

**Update:**

If you don't want the default resources `managedVirtualNetworks` and `integrationRuntimes`, simply remove them, then the **`Template.json`** will be like below, it also works fine.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "defaultValue": "myv2datafactory",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "version": {
            "defaultValue": "V2",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "eastus",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "apiVersion": {
            "defaultValue": "2018-06-01",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "tagsByResource": {
            "type": "Object"
        },
        "vNetEnabled": {
            "defaultValue": false,
            "type": "Bool"
        },
        "publicNetworkAccess": {
            "defaultValue": true,
            "type": "Bool"
        },
        "gitConfigureLater": {
            "defaultValue": true,
            "type": "Bool"
        },
        "gitRepoType": {
            "defaultValue": "FactoryVSTSConfiguration",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitAccountName": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitProjectName": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitRepositoryName": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitCollaborationBranch": {
            "defaultValue": "master",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gitRootFolder": {
            "defaultValue": "/",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
            "defaultValue": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "type": "Object"
        },
        "userAssignedIdentitiesStr": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "vaultBaseUrl": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "keyName": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "keyVersion": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "enableCMK": {
            "defaultValue": false,
            "type": "Bool"
        },
        "cmkIdentity": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": "[ if(contains(parameters('tagsByResource'), 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories'), parameters('tagsByResource')['Microsoft.DataFactory/factories'], json('{}')) ]",
            "identity": "[if(parameters('enableCMK'),json(parameters('userAssignedIdentitiesStr')), parameters('userAssignedIdentities'))]",
            "properties": {
                "repoConfiguration": "[if(bool(parameters('gitConfigureLater')), json('null'), json(concat('{\"type\": \"', parameters('gitRepoType'), '\",','\"accountName\": \"', parameters('gitAccountName'), '\",','\"repositoryName\": \"', parameters('gitRepositoryName'), '\",', if(equals(parameters('gitRepoType'), 'FactoryVSTSConfiguration'), concat('\"projectName\": \"', parameters('gitProjectName'), '\",'), ''),'\"collaborationBranch\": \"', parameters('gitCollaborationBranch'), '\",','\"rootFolder\": \"', parameters('gitRootFolder'), '\"}')))]",
                "publicNetworkAccess": "[if(bool(parameters('publicNetworkAccess')), 'Enabled', 'Disabled')]",
                "encryption": "[if(bool(parameters('enableCMK')), json(concat('{\"identity\":{\"userAssignedIdentity\":\"', parameters('cmkIdentity'), '\"},','\"VaultBaseUrl\": \"', parameters('vaultBaseUrl'), '\",','\"KeyName\": \"', parameters('keyName'), '\",','\"KeyVersion\": \"', parameters('keyVersion'), '\"}')), json('null'))]"
            },
            "resources": [
            ],
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('version'), 'V2')]"
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories",
            "apiVersion": "2015-01-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[if(equals(parameters('version'), 'V1'), parameters('location'), 'eastus')]",
            "tags": "[ if(contains(parameters('tagsByResource'), 'Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories'), parameters('tagsByResource')['Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories'], json('{}')) ]",
            "properties": {},
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('version'), 'V1')]"
        }
    ]
}
```

Test result:

[image]

[image]